# Navigation component - How to clear history for nested graph only?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation

I use navigation component with BottomNavigationView where each tab has own nested graph.
The task is to organise backstack accordingly -
For ex.: User go to tab 2, navigate through nested graph by 3 pages, then open 3rd tab and navigate through nested  graph by 2 pages.
If it navigate back the way should be: *(tab 3 page 2) -> (tab 3 page 1) -> (tab 2 page 1) -> (tab 1 page 1)*

If I understand tight I need to clear backstack for nested graph when I go out from it but I cant to find a solution. Multiple backstack lead me to each previous page between graphs

Answer (score 1):

Make use of popUpTo and popUpToInclusive attributes inside actions in graph.
refer this documentation, https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate#pop

Comment: I suppose that popUpTo hardcode the "previous" fragment but it could be a different tab. My example it is not the only way. It means that after user open new tab previous one should clear own backstack and open start destination next time - after click to tab or go back from other one

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
binding.bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener { item ->
    NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, findNavController())
    findNavController().popBackStack(item.itemId, inclusive = false)

    true
}
```